# How to calculate accuracy of LDO

Tags: power-supply, power, ldo, accuracy

I will be using a TPS7H1101A LDO and wanted to calculate the accuracy of it. I see in the datasheet they list the output voltage accuracy of +/- 2%.
I think this number in some datasheets covers the line and load regulation as well but not sure as they are specified separately.
Line and load regulation are .07%/V and .08%/A respectively. Do I need to add these in as well or are they covered by the 2% value?
If so, I am assuming I would need to know the input voltage variation from the supply feeding this one?

Thanks!
[datasheet link](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7h1101a-sp.pdf?ts=1634341932084&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS7H1101A-SP)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The datasheet explicitly mentions input and output variations, so line and load regulations are covered. The (1) note just mentions what is covered by production tests.

Comment: Oops missed that. Thanks! So the only other factor I guess would be the accuracy of the resistor values?

Comment: Yes. The datasheet mentions the full range. I'd recommend looking at the SMD datasheet for further information. You'd get actual testing data from the vendor if you have the date code

Answer (score 0):

> *Do I need to add these in as well or are they covered by the 2% value?*

The first page states this: -

`±2% accuracy over line, load, and temperature`

But, it's likely that's a typical value. However, having read further into the data sheet it does look like this is the maximum value for output accuracy given the line and load conditions specified.